# XmlSerializer Issue In Unit Test

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, uwp

So I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to find a resolution to after searching the internet. The main issue is that when I'm creating a `XmlSerializer` using a custom defined type it fails with no reason why. This only occurs in the unit test I've created that calls this function. In the application where it is being used the code executes as intended and all is well in the world. Below is some code snippets that show what is going on.

```
public class ClassA
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        Id = string.Empty;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ClassB()
    {
        Id = string.Empty;
    }
}

public class SerializeClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string RandomString { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    public List<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    public List<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Int32 Count { get; set; }

    public SerializeClass()
    {
        RandomString = string.Empty;
        ClassAs = new List<ClassA>();
        ClassBs = new List<ClassB>();
        Count = 0;
    }
}


public class XmlReaderClass
{
    private SerializeClass _serializeClass;

    public async Task<bool> Initialize()
    {
        bool loaded = false;

        // If the rules are empty create and load them.
        if (_rules == null)
        {
            _rules = new Rules();

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///FileToReadIn.xml"));
            Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeClass));
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stream);
            _serializeClass = (serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader()) as SerializeClass);

            loaded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            loaded = true;
        }

        return loaded;
    }
}
```

So only when unit testing does the Initialize function fail on the line with

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeClass));.
```

I need to read in this XML to perform unit testing on functionality related to the data in the XML file.

Comment: Can you show us the exact error please?

Comment: It doesn't give an error the testing just stops and it shows the test as passing.

Comment: Oh! It's because you're using an async method!  You need to make the test handle that.  Changing the header of the test method to `public async Task MyTest()` should solve it.

Comment: You are my savior. That was it! Thanks a ton. Now to figure out to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Great news :)  Added the answer now ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your method is an async method, you need to make sure the testing framework can await it.  To do that, you should make the testing method's signature like this:

```
public async Task MyTest()
```